# C Quicksort (linked list) segmentation fault

Tags: c, quicksort, read-data

I have to create a quicksort on a linked list (in C). 
I have my first and last pointer an the pivot (in this code it's the first element of the list). 
The structs I have to use:

```
typedef struct list_element list_element;

struct list_element {
    char *password;
    int count;
    list_element* next;
};

typedef struct list list;

struct list {
    list_element* first;
    list_element* last;
};
```

I have a file with 100 passwords and counts.
Like this:
password1 123 (next line) password2 435 (next line) password3 133 ...
The passwords have to be sorted (according to their count) in the end of this programm.
There isn't needed any extra memory allociation for the left and right lists because I only have to use the next pointers. (That's what the hint in the exercise says.)

The given main-function:

```
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Nutzung: %s <Dateiname>\n",args[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    list mylist;
    init_list(&mylist);
    read_data(args[1],&mylist);
    qsort_list(&mylist);
    printf("Sortierte Liste:\n");
    print_list(&mylist);
    free_list(&mylist);
    return 0;
}
```

I have initialized my list:

```
void init_list(list* mylist)
{
    mylist->first = NULL;
    mylist->last = NULL;
}
```

And insert a new element at end (passwort = passwords in file, hauefigkeit = counts in file):

```
void insert_list(list_element* le, list* mylist)
{
    if (mylist->first != NULL) {
        le->next = mylist->last;
        mylist->last = le;
        le->next= NULL;
    }
    else {
        mylist->last->next = le;
        mylist->last = le;
        mylist->last->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Read data from file:

```
void read_data(char* filename, list* mylist)
{
    FILE *file_in = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    if (file_in == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open input file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[999] = "0";

    char *passwort = (char*) calloc(1,sizeof(passwort));
    int haeufigkeit = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file_in) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", passwort, &haeufigkeit);

        list_element* le = (list_element*)calloc(1,sizeof(list_element));

        for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
            le->password[i] = passwort[i];
        }
        le->count = haeufigkeit;
        le->next = NULL;

        insert_list(le, mylist);
    }
    fclose(file_in);
}
```

Partition of the list:

```
list_element* partition( list* input, list* left, list* right )
{
    list_element* pivot = NULL;
    if (input->first != NULL) {
        list_element* temp;
        pivot = input->first;
        input->first = input->first->next;
        pivot->next = NULL;
        left->first = NULL;
        right->first = NULL;

        while (input->first != NULL) {
            if((pivot->count)>(input->first->count)){
                temp=input->first->next;
                insert_list(input->first, left);
                input->first=temp;
            } 
            else {
                temp = input->first->next;
                insert_list(input->first, right);
                input->first = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return pivot;
}
```

The actual quicksort:

```
void qsort_list(list* mylist)
{
    if(mylist->first == mylist->last){
    }

    else{
        list* left = calloc(1,sizeof(list));
        list* right= calloc(1,sizeof(list));
        list_element* pivot = partition(mylist, left, right);

        qsort_list(left);
        qsort_list(right);

        if(left->first == NULL){
            mylist->first = pivot;
        }
        else{
            mylist->first = left->first;
            left->last->next = pivot;
        }

        if(right->first == NULL){
            pivot->next = NULL;
            mylist->last = pivot;
        }
        else{
            pivot->next = right->first;
            mylist->last = right->last;
        }

        free(right);
        free(left);

    }
}
```

In the end print list:

```
void print_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element *elem = mylist->first;
    while (elem != NULL) {
        printf("%s %d\n", elem->password, elem->count);
        elem = elem->next;
    }     
}
```

And free list:

```
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element *current;
    list_element *second;
    current = mylist->first;
    while (current != NULL) {
        second = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = second;
    }
}
```

Syntax should be ok. GCC (c99, Wall) compiles without any problems.

But there is an segmentation fault. I have been searching for hours now and I have no idea where the problem could be. Maybe you can help me with this problem.

---

After the first two answers there isn't any segmentation fault. But still have a problem with read_data function. 
The program can't read the passworts correctly. Maybe i misunderstood you answers in relation to the read function.
That's the current function:

```
void read_data(char* filename, list* mylist)
{
    FILE *file_in = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    if (file_in == NULL) { 
        perror("Could not open input file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[999] = "0";

    int haeufigkeit = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file_in) != NULL) {

        char passwort[100];

        sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", passwort, &haeufigkeit);

        list_element* le = (list_element*)    

    calloc(1,sizeof(list_element));


        le->password = passwort;
        le->count = haeufigkeit;
        le->next = NULL;

        insert_list(le, mylist);
    }
    fclose(file_in);
}
```

Comment: Could you please debug it, and tell us in which line the seg. fault is happening?

Answer (score 1):

As Leonardo Alves Machado pointed out, the first reflex when having trouble with a C/C++ program is to run it with a debugger like [`gdb`](http://www.cprogramming.com/gdb.html). Here is the basics:

```
gcc -g main.c -o main
gdb main
(gdb) run
```

Note the `-g` compilation flag: this will add debug information to the executable.

---

In `read_data`, the lines

```
for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
    le->password[i] = passwort[i];
}
```

really bug me. You allocate space for `passwort` (which you never free by the way) and try to copy it to `le->password`, which is a simple pointer (no allocated space). What you actually need is to make `le->password` *point to* `passwort`, i.e.

```
le->password = passwort;
```

In `free_list`, don't forget to deallocate the `passwort` space before deallocating the `list_element` space with:

```
while (current != NULL) {
    second = current->next;
    free(current->password);
    free(current);
    current = second;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you and sorry for not using the debugger before asking for solutions here. There are no segmentation faults left. But i still have a problem with the read_data funktion. The program is  not able to read the passworts correctly. I will edit my question und put the new data_read funktion in there. Maybe you can help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first issues your program encounters is that `read_data()` does not allocate enough space for `passwort`.  It's unclear, actually, why you are dynamically allocating this at all, but given that you are doing so, `sizeof(passwort)` is the size of one pointer to char (since that's what `passwort` is) -- probably either 4 or 8 bytes.  Later, you seem to assume that the allocated space is 100 bytes long when you (attempt to) copy its contents into a list element.  Why not simply declare it as a 100-char array?

```
char passwort[100];
```

Indeed, if you also declare `list_element.passwort` the same way then your password-copying code inside the loop will be correct, albeit a bit non-idiomatic.

As it is, that code is problematic, as @Derlin observes.  His proposed solution is incorrect, however; you must not make the list elements point to the local `passwort` as long as that is allocated only once for the whole routine.  Then all list elements will have the same password string, which is not what you want.  If you want your list elements to contain pointers to the passwords, as they do now, then you'll want to move the declaration and allocation of `passwort` *inside* the loop, so that you get separate password space allocated for each list element.  Then the suggestion to assign `le->password = passwort` would be correct.

---

Another early issue is that your `insert_list()` function is badly broken.

Consider first what happens when you try to insert an element into an empty list, as initialized by `init_list()`.  The list's `next` and `last` members will both be null, and `insert_list()` will therefore attempt to execute this code:

```
    mylist->last->next = le;
    mylist->last = le;
    mylist->last->next = NULL;
```

Observe that `mylist->last` is null, therefore the first line invokes undefined behavior by attempting to dereference a null pointer.  A segmentation fault is an eminently plausible observed result.  You might fix that by changing the first of those lines to

```
    mylist->next = le;
```

Now consider what happens when you try to insert into a non-empty list.  In that case, you execute these lines:

```
    le->next = mylist->last;
    mylist->last = le;
    le->next= NULL;
```

Since your intention is to insert the new element at the end (i.e. to *append* it), it is odd that you set the new element's `next` pointer to the list's last element.  It is especially odd that you later overwrite that value with `NULL`.  You seem to have it backward: you want to set the initial `last` element to point to the new element as its next element, not the other way around:

```
    mylist->last->next = le;
```

Indeed, that's exactly the code that was wrong for the empty-list case, but it's fine when the list is non-empty.

Overall, your function also suffers from an odd lack of parallelism and some hidden code duplication.  I'd probably write the overall function something more like this:

```
void append_to_list(list_element* le, list* mylist)
{
    le->next= NULL;
    if (mylist->first != NULL) {
        mylist->last->next = le;
        mylist->last = le;
    }
    else {
        mylist->first = le;
        mylist->last = le;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. And sorry for not using the debugger before asking for solutions here. There's no segmentation fault anymore, but I still have a problem with reading the passwort.